# Update component JS for chart when component refresh\re-render

Tags: javascript, laravel, laravel-livewire

I am using ApexChart and added that in the Livewire component,

```
   <select class="form-select form-select-solid" aria-label="Select example" wire:model.change="expiry">
                <option>Select Expiry</option>
                <option value="2024-03-28">2024-03-28</option>
                <option value="2024-04-25">2024-04-25</option>
    </select>

    <div class="card-body" id="chart">
            --This is chart
    </div>

@push('scripts')
         ......
        var chart = new ApexCharts(document.querySelector("#chart"), options);
        chart.render();
@endpush
```

When the page loads, the component loads and I can see a chart with correct data. So far all good.

Now, I have `select` option in the component and based on the selected value, data are being queried in DB and I get the correct data,

I can see the component getting refreshed, but I don't see any updates in chart data, and even `console.log()` doesn't print anything, so it looks like the script inside the component doesn't reactivate.

So how to refresh scripts which are inside livewire component itself?